# How to run selenium python package containing x86 binary on aarch64?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When trying to run a browser benchmark using `selenium`, I encounter an error since the package tries to run the included binary `webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager` which is a `x86_64` executable.

Looking at the sources for the package, as distributed by [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/#files), you can see that this file is distributed as a binary, not source. Is there a source repository for `selenium` from which I can compile the binary for `aarch64`, or am I stuck running it on `x86`?

Any known workarounds?

##### More context on setup

Python version: 3.7.5

`selenium` package version: 4.10.0

I am trying to run an existing OpenBenchmarks benchmark for `selenium`. I have verified that the benchmark runs on `x86` machines. Also, I have modified the benchmark slightly to run the browser (specifically Firefox) in headless mode. This also runs on `x86`, and I think is orthogonal to my issue.